# Change current url and fill out a text field

Tags: javascript

With JavaScript how can I fill out this text field on a website? I'm trying to implement autofill of forms.

```
<div class="address_line_one_box">
        <label class="inputLabel" for="firstname">First Name:<em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" size="41" maxlength="96" id="firstname"> 
    </div>
```

this is my current code. Changing the url works but filling out the textfield does not.

```
<body onload = "myFunction();">

<script>
function myFunction() {
   window.location.href = "www.example.com";
   document.getElementById("firstname").value = "My name";
}
</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? You are redirecting to other page before you set the value of your field.

Comment: I want to set the value of the text field on the redirected page.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("firstname").value = "My name";
```